# Find distance to the nearest city from one table to another table in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

i have a grid table that contains the lat, long, city name, district, and the distance from the city to the district. I wanted to find the distance of the user to the nearest city.

My code to find the distance of the user to the nearest city

```
select r.id, r.lat, r.long, r.city, r.dist from
    (
        select q.id, q.lat, q.long, q.city, q.dist, rank() over (partition by q.lat, q.long order by q.dist) as seq from 
        (
            select ul.id, ul.lat::numeric, ul.long::numeric, city.city, latlngdist(ul.lat::numeric, ul.long::numeric,
                        city.lat, city.lon) as dist
                from
                    public.user_loc ul, 
                    (SELECT city, lat::numeric, lon::numeric FROM public.grid_loc ) city
        ) q
    ) r 
where r.seq = 1
order by dist asc
limit 100;
```

Below are the screenshot of the user_loc table

[image: user_loc table]

Below are the screenshot of the grid_loc table

[image: grid_loc table]

The code that i used are currently running, but it is super slow to query 100k+ data (Took me more than 1000s), the latlngdist function are a haversine function that i've created to find the distance. Would keen to know how to do it with matching the lat and long and find the distance

Comment: Why are you using rank (partitioned) by lat/long?  Are you expecting multiple cities at the same location?  Also - is there much of a difference between the time it takes to run query "q" (vs. the overall query)

Comment: Hmm actually you're right, if i use partitioning it will expect multiple cities at the same location. For now no difference if i run query "q" versus the overall query

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take a look at PostGIS.  According to their site:

> PostGIS is a spatial database extender for PostgreSQL
>   object-relational database. It adds support for geographic objects
>   allowing location queries to be run in SQL.

Here's a use case that matches your example: http://www.sqlexamples.info/SPAT/postgis_nearest_point.htm

Comment: Hmm actually since i'm going to visualise this in Metabase, i can't use PostGIS thats why i need to use the old fashion way...

Comment: I'm not sure that that rules out PostGIS.  If Metabase can connect to Postres normally, adding PostGIS probably won't alter that.  If you do stick with standard Postgres you'll still need to do a full table scan and perform the calculation on every row.  Did you look at my question about the rank/partitioning?

Comment: Yup i've checked your comment out and still trying to figure out how to code this in PostGIS